# The suffixes "-ridden" and "-infested"

Tags: suffixes, compounds

We say compounds like "**mosquito-ridden**" and "**shark-infested**", but I haven't heard "**mosquito-infested**" or "**shark-ridden**".

My question is that can we use the suffixes "**-ridden**" and "**-infested**" interchangeably regardless of the amount and significance of the damage that an excess of something can cause?

For example, can we say "**mosquito-infested**" or "**shark-ridden**"? Wouldn't it seem funny or unnatural?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've observed, some combinations of *-ridden* and *-infested* are more common than others. *Shark-ridden* is [far less common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shark-ridden,shark-infested&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) than *shark-infested*, while both  *mosquito-ridden* and *mosquito-infested* can be found in literature.

*Ridden* and *infested* both indicate an unpleasant excess of something, and could stand alone—

> The marsh is ridden with mosquitoes.
>
> The bay is infested with sharks.

— but whether forming a compound or not, there are slight differences.

*Infested* carries a connotation of being overrun or overcome by a pest or parasite, especially one that swarms: *maggot-infested wounds*, *doily-infested parlors*, *teenager-infested shopping centers*, etc. One can speak of disease in this way, e.g. *cholera-infested villages* or *tumor-infested kidneys*, but most non-count nouns do not "infest"; one almost never encounters a *angst-infested* author.

*Ridden*, on the other hand, suggest a chronic or endemic condition, especially where the thing in excess is an internal or intrinsic rather than external phenomenon: a *slum-ridden neighborhood*, *cliché-ridden novel*, or *worry-ridden father*. A dog with fleas could be either *flea-ridden* or *flea-infested*, but to my ear the former suggests resignation and the latter alarm. *Ridden* is also more commonly joined with non-count nouns: *torment-ridden* prisoners and *violence-ridden* provinces are more common than their *torment-infested* and *violence-infested* counterparts.

Of course, certain formulations have become set phrases, or at least more popular than others, and not all conditions can be expressed using one or the other. Waters are always *ice-infested* or *shark-infested*, almost never *ice-ridden* or *shark-ridden*. On the other hand, one is *debt-ridden* or *guilt-ridden*, never *debt-infested* or *guilt-infested*. And one is neither *age-ridden* nor *age-infested*. As for the pond, it can be either [*mosquito-ridden* or *mosquito-infested*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mosquito-ridden,mosquito-infested&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), so wear plenty of repellent.

Comment: Thank you. It was very informative. I like the part that proves teenagers are parasites! :D